# minion run_list using salt master

Tags: salt-stack

Installed salt-minions using saltstack cookbook and different versions of this cookbook been used while installing as minions got connected at different times. Now, would like to know what minion is using what version of the cookbook so is there a way to find from salt-master ?

Comment: What cookbook? There's no record of which instructions you used to install something.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to know the versions of the minions you are running:

```sh
salt-run manage.versions
```

In Jinja there is an execution module:

```
{{ salt["test.version"]() }}
```

Or on the command line:

```sh
salt-call --version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the salt version using grains.fetch like this:

```
salt '*' grains.fetch saltversion
```

Source: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/grains/